# How to get one site page data into another site page in WordPress multisite

Tags: wordpress

I have WordPress multisite and I want to crate one common page in my default site and also used this page data in to all the site so when I update the data in this page all site have the same data

Answer (score 0):

I understand your concern, for that, you will need to put this type of code, as in the multisite you will need to set global site id and you can get the data by below code for ex:

```
<?php 
global $blog_id;
switch_to_blog(1); // site id from which you want to get the data
$pageid = 903; // post id from which you want to get the data
$post = get_post( $pageid ); 

restore_current_blog(); // restore to current blog
?>
```

Comment: Ohhhh buddy you are awesome I try this right now and it's working for me thanks a lot have grate days